# Flutter Firestorage getDownloadUrl() returns NoSuchMethodError

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, injectable

inside my Flutter app I'm trying to upload an image to Firebase Storage and get the URL afterwards. The image is getting uploaded and I can see it in the web interface, but when I call getDownloadUrl() on a valid reference (I can see the relative path with debugger) I get `type 'NoSuchMethodError' is not a subtype of type 'Exception'` and the actual error is happening inside `method_channel_reference.dart` where for some reason, where `storage` is null and as such `storage.app` throws the Error.

```
 @override
  Future<String /*!*/ > getDownloadURL() async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = await MethodChannelFirebaseStorage.channel
          .invokeMapMethod<String, dynamic>(
              'Reference#getDownloadURL', <String, dynamic>{
        'appName': storage.app.name,
        'maxOperationRetryTime': storage.maxOperationRetryTime,
        'maxUploadRetryTime': storage.maxUploadRetryTime,
        'maxDownloadRetryTime': storage.maxDownloadRetryTime,
        'bucket': storage.bucket,
        'path': fullPath,
      });

      return data['downloadURL'];
    } catch (e) {
      throw convertPlatformException(e);
    }
  }
```

The upload code is this:

```
final uploadTask = _firebaseStorage.ref().child(storagePath).putFile(recipeImage);

    try {
      await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
      final url = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      return right<RecipeFailure, String>(url);
    } catch (e) {
      return left<RecipeFailure, String>(RecipeFailure.imageUploadFailed());
    }
```

I'm using

```
firebase_core: ^0.7.0
firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
```

I tried cleaning, rebuilding and downgrading dependencies. At this point I don't how where else to look. I guess the issue is with the storage instance being removed or not initialized at all, but why does the upload work then? Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed from

```
@lazySingleton
FirebaseStorage get firebaseStorage => FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(bucket: "bucket-url");
```

to this

```
@lazySingleton
FirebaseStorage get firebaseStorage => FirebaseStorage.instance;
```

the error disappeared and everything was working properly.

The main reason I have the bucket URLs there was because I was working with project flavors and two Firebase projects. The seperate `google-services.json` seem to be enough for Android (haven't tested iOS until now). However, why the upload was working, but download not is still a big mistery to me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you, but you can store the link in each upload in the `document` for each product or user wherever it is.

In this method, for example, you can retrieve the **link file** from the same `document`, and you do not need another way to retrieve it.

In this code you can upload the file and restore the `downloadUrl` when you have finished uploading the file.

```
 static Future<dynamic> uploadFile(
      {@required File imageFile, @required String folderPath}) async {
    String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

    Reference reference =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(folderPath).child(fileName);

    TaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await reference.putFile(imageFile);
    // TaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot =  uploadTask.snapshot;

    print(storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());

    var dounloadUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    return dounloadUrl;
  }
```